# How to discard some number of messages in rabbitmQ

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

I have a use case where I need to get data from a queue on an exchange that I dont have control on.
the usecase is that from this queue I get messages constantly. Just wonder if in rabbitmq or by using/writing a plugin I can discard 90% of the messages at a time before saving them to my local datastore. The reason for this is that I'm not capable of storing all the messages but 10% of it.
Obviously one way is in my application to do so. but I wonder if there is a way to do it on rabbitmq level.

Just wonder if you have any thoughts/solutions on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have control of the exchange, you're pretty much limited to doing it in your app.

You can bulk-reject messages using a nack - here's the help page:
http://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html

Answer (score 0):

Due to the AMQP specs, a rabbitmq queue passes its messages to the connected consumers in a round robin algorithm. So if your code is the sole consumer of the rabbitmq queue & you want your application to neglect about 90% of recieved messages and process only remaining 10% then,....
connect to the same queue using 10 different consumers simultaneously (all may be written in same language or diff. dose not matter) and write your message processing logic in any one or two of them....abandon the rest 8/9 consumers(these will be used by rabbitmq [and conceptually by us] to drain off about 90% of messages)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply consume the messages and do nothing about it. Using rabbitmqadmin is the easiest way to do this as below:

`rabbitmqadmin get queue=queuename requeue=false count=1`